# Downfall - The Riddle

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, lateral-thinking, steganography

> If forgotten, I will be back in September.
>   If you think I am feminine, I will show you a stop sign.
>   If you are afraid of heights, I will throw you in the sea at twilights.
>   If any mis event happens (heh!, so lame), you know which insect to blame.
>   When you are sixty and low on your defenses, don't go blaming your senses.
>   Are you deaf? I vent my anger, don't you dare forget about indie's blabber.
>   Lets cutoff our conversation, its quack anyways.
>   Let the path reenacts for us, which we built with our hands.
>   And when we are trustworthy enough, there will be only one...
>   Nonetheless, we think we won, "And Then There Were None"....

Hint :

> For each couplet, first part is part of the question and second part is an answer

Comment: I would love to see what exactly is **the question** here.

Answer (score 13):

The "Downfall" is actually

> a countdown from 10 to 0.
>  The important thing to see is that the lower number of each pair is written twice, because of the pattern known from nursery rhymes and literature:
>  10 *of something* were *doing something*, one *did something* and then there were 9...
>  9 *of something* were *doing something*, one *did something* and then there were 8...
>  and so on until *none* of the objects is left.
>  For example [Ten_Little_Indians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Little_Indians#Minstrel_song) - I used this example to explain each line below
>  It may refer to **And Then There Were None** novel by Agatha Christie, as the phrase appears in the riddle itself, or just the general idea of this type of a song.

If forgotten,

> forgot**ten** means 10
> *Ten little Injuns standin' in a line,*

I will be back in September.

> September is the 9th month
> *One toddled home and then there were nine;*

If you think I am feminine,

> femi**nine** means 9
> *Nine little Injuns swingin' on a gate,*

I will show you stop sign.

> Stop sign is octagonal which means 8
> *One tumbled off and then there were eight.*

If you are afraid of heights,

> h**eight**s means 8
> *Eight little Injuns gayest under heav'n.*

I will throw you in the sea at twilights.

> The "Seven Seas" which means 7
> *One went to sleep and then there were seven;*

If any mis event happens (heh!, so lame),

> mi**s even**t means 7
> *Seven little Injuns cuttin' up their tricks,*

you know which insect to blame.

> Insects have 6 legs
> *One broke his neck and then there were six.*

When you are sixty and low on your defenses,

> **six**ty means 6
> *Six little Injuns all alive,*

don't go blaming your senses.

> There are 5 senses
> *One kicked the bucket and then there were five;*

Are you deaf? I vent my anger,

> dea**f? I ve**nt means 5
> *Five little Injuns on a cellar door,*

don't you dare forget about indie's blabber.

> indie = Indiana Jones, about whom 4 movies were officially released by now
> *One tumbled in and then there were four.*

Lets cutoff our conversation,

> cutof**f our** means 4
> *Four little Injuns up on a spree,*

its quack anyways.

> Hendrick Peter Godfried **Quack** had 3 names??
> Donald Duck (who says "quack") has 3 nephews??
> *One got fuddled and then there were three;*

Let the path reenacts for us,

> pa**th ree**nacts means 3
> *Three little Injuns out on a canoe,*

which we built with our hands.

> We have 2 hands
> *One tumbled overboard and then there were two*

And when we are trustworthy enough,

> trus**two**rthy means 2
> *Two little Injuns foolin' with a gun,*

there will be only one...

> one = 1
> *One shot t'other and then there was one;*

Nonetheless we think we won,

> N**one**theless means 1
> *One little Injun livin' all alone,*

"And Then There Were None"....

> None = 0
> *He got married and then there were none.*

Comment: Wow, way to resurrect an unsolved question! Looks spot on to me... +1

Comment: @Stiv This would be a waste to leave such a question unanswered forever ;)

Comment: @Stiv, you are realllly close, like real close, I reformatted the puzzle, have a look. I don't know how to explain this without giving spoilers :)

Comment: @smriti I am arfaid that it did not change much ;) Consider posting some hints.

Comment: @oleslaw - I think mention of the tag 'maths' will help? You are on right track with '10 of something were doing something, one did something and then there were 9'

Answer (score 3):

I spent too much time to not post my findings

The best idea I could come up with is

> Tomb Raider

Because

If forgotten,
I will be back in September.

> the Tomb Raider remake "Shadow of the Tomb Raider" comes out next September

If you think I am feminine,
I will show you stop sign.

> Lara Croft is a woman, but not "feminine"

If you are afraid of heights,
I will through you in the sea at twilights.

> Lara Croft jumped into water from height many times

If any mis event happens,
you know which insect to blame.

> This refers to not being able to trigger event because of bugs (Tomb raider games are kinda buggy)

When you are sixty and low on your defenses,
don't go blaming your senses.

> This is about losing 40 percent of your health to trap that was impossible to see???

Are you deaf? I vent my anger,
Don’t you dare forget about indie's blabber.

> Being mad about die repeatedly maybe??

Lets cutoff our conversation,
its quack anyways.

> no clue

Let the path reenacts for us,
which we built with our hands.

> This refers how tomb Raider is a remake

And when we are trustworthy enough,
there will be only one...

> ????

Nonetheless we think we won,
"And Then There Were None"....

> This talk about how when you beat the game you actually have archived nothing

Comment: +1(I gave +1 just by reading "tomb raider" )though some clues seems to fit nicely, unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: In my heart, Lara Croft is the answer to everything

Answer (score 0):

Possible partial answer:

> Are you a mosquito ?
>
>  Its the insect buzzing in your ear, that comes out at dusk and can transmit diseases when you are old and you immunity is low. I will answer the rest of the clues if I am close. Can't think of the rest right now, will add as I do.
>  Did you mean "throw you in the sea" ?

Comment: sorry, this is not it